# Python equivalent to C#'s ListView?

Tags: c#, python, listview

I am creating a simple GUI program to manage priorities. The thing is, I am coming from C# to Python, and my question is what exactly is Python's equivalent for a ListView in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which GUI package you go for.  For WX, it is `wx.ListCtrl` and for tk it is `listbox`.  Probably a good idea to have a look through some docs:

https://wxpython.org/ for WX

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter for tk

Comment: Thanks, I'm with Tkinter.

Comment: no problem, happy to help